# OS X El Capitan download button is grayed out

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I'm currently running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 and trying to upgrade to OS X El Capitan. I'm in the App Store on the OS X El Capitan page:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1018109117?mt=12

However, the download button is grayed out and there's really no way for me to upgrade. See image below:

[image]

How to solve this predicament?

Comment: Are you signed into the same Apple ID that 'bought' the current OS? If not, sign out from the Store menu & back in with the correct ID.

Answer (score 1):

Just restarted the machine and that solved the issue. Now it's downloading.